# live for jquery elastic plugin?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

i use jquery elastic plugin for expanding a textbox. it works great but i want to use this on a textbox that is added to the DOM with ajax but unfortunately this plugin has no live built-in function.

is there a way to solve this?

http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have control over the textarea creation, then simply call `.elastic()` on the textarea once it is created:

```
// In whatever AJAX callback creates the textarea...
var newTextarea = $('<textarea></textarea>');

// Append the element to the DOM wherever it belongs...
parentElement.append(newTextarea);

// Add elastic behavior.
newTextarea.elastic();
```

Comment: Presumably, since you're calling a plugin, you don't have control over textarea creation - $.live is a better solution...

Comment: The poster never said that the textarea was created via a plugin, they only said they were using a plugin to extend its behavior.  It seems wasteful to me to add a live() event handler when you know when the textarea is created and have control over it.

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery 1.4, you can do this:

```
$("textarea").live("focus", function() {
    $(this).elastic().die("focus");
});
```

jQuery 1.3.x does not support the focus event for live(), so it gets a little trickier:

```
$("textarea").live("keydown", elasticize).live("mousedown", elasticize);

function elasticize() {
    $(this).elastic().die("keydown").die("mousedown");
}
```

The `die` calls are there so elastic is only called once for each textarea.

Comment: but why would anyone use 1.3 when 1.4 is out there?=)

Comment: hm i noticed that ive got 1.3 and 1.4 isnt downloadable on their site..where can u get it?

Comment: 1.4 is still in alpha - http://blog.jquery.com/2009/12/18/jquery-14-alpha-2-released/

Answer (score 0):

The other answers suggest destroying the focus handler, but that may break other dependencies.

Instead, you can tag your textarea with class="elastic". Once elastic is initialized, you can remove the "elastic" class to avoid repeat inits.

`$(document)
    .on('focus','textarea.elastic',function(e) { 
      $(this).removeClass('elastic').elastic();
    })`