# Using a .live for a key up for a text area in jquery

Tags: jquery, live

```
$textarea.keyup(function(){ update(); });
```

I tired to add the live function to it. Like the following

```
$textarea.live(keyup(function(){ update(); }));
```

but I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: keyup is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$textarea.live("keyup", function () {
    update();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't give a error but still didn't work.I looked up more information and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943552/live-for-jquery-elastic-plugin/1943581#1943581 helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use livequery? It's easy and works fine. If you have an array of objects use a class. In this case a use a class named matriz_producto_keyup. When I add new data with ajax, livequery recognizes the event and proceeds to execute your script.

```
$(".matriz_producto_keyup").livequery("keyup", function(e){
   //if yoy want to know the id
   var id=$(this).attrib("id");
   alert(id);
});
```

Enjoy the code.
http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/live/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Good syntax of `.live` is `.live( eventType, handler )` 
At least, write it like this : `$textarea.live('keyup', update);` if you use a real handler or `$textarea.live('keyup', function(){update();});` if you only use a function once.

Comment: As of Jquery 1.7 live is deprecated and is replaced with the .on() function

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$textarea.live('keyup',update);
```

**PK**